# Query the Active Directory for all users with a custom attribute

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm using a custom UserPrincipalEx-class since I want to query the Active Directory for a custom attribute "costCenter". The custom UserPrincipalEx-Class therefore has a DirectoryProperty("costCenter") added. The basic and long-running (3 minutes) version looks like this:

```
// create domain context
PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "myDomainController");

// define the query-by-example principal
UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(context);

// create the principal searcher    
PrincipalSearcher searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

// find all matches
foreach (var hit in searcher.FindAll())
{
    //do incredible stuff here
}
```

Now, using a customized class "UserPrincipalEx" that is extended for the custom attribute "costCenter":

```
UserPrincipalEx qbeUser = new UserPrincipalEx(context);
qbeUser.costCenter = "123";
```

makes the query execute almost as fast as light. But what I really need would be to query for all users that just *have* a costCenter (not all do so).

So my question is: **How to use an extended "Query-By-Example" principal to search for principals that just *have* a custom attribute?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reverted to using a

```
Parallel.ForEach
```

in order to speed the whole thing up. The ForEach-Loop runs over an IEnumerable with all values of the custom attribute I'm interested in, furbishing the UserPrincipalEx-attribute with one of theses values and adding the results to a list.

Not really what I was looking for, but effective: From 3 Minutes down to ~15 seconds.